# Isn't this equation linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\left(y-1\right)$

Hi !

I was reading through my differential equation book and encountered this equation.

Isn't this a linear differential equation?

The book says this is a nonlinear differential equation.

I am confused with the linearity of this equation.

It would be greatly helpful if someone could give me an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your equation has the form

$$y'=a (x)y+b (x)   \tag E$$
with

$$a (x)=-b (x)=\frac {1}{2\sqrt {x}} $$
thus it is first order linear differential equation.

its general solution is the sum of the solution of the equation
$$y'=a (x)y $$ and a particular solution of the complete equation $(E) $.

observe that $y=1$ is a particular solution and the general solution is
$$y_G=\lambda e^{\sqrt {x}}+1$$
for $x>0$.